# How to load tui-calendar by specific date or date-range

Tags: calendar, tui

I am trying to load TOAST UI Calendar by specific date or date-range but by default it's loaded by today's date... can anyone help me to sort it out...

Answer (score 2):

I think .setDate is the method that you are looking for

https://nhn.github.io/tui.calendar/latest/Calendar#setDate

Just use it as the calendar loads.

Comment: It seems to be the only way to do it at the moment